# Retrofit2 Api Call Error not showing the Result in Recycler view

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, retrofit2

This is the API

```
 INPUT:
        center_id:4
                tabID:952888062222222
        patient_search: 98

  OUTPUT:
{
    "status": true,
    "result": [
        {
            "patient_id": "3",
            "gen_patient_id": "pmhsola00003",
            "first_name": "Sama",
            "last_name": "Patil",
            "p_mobile": "2398322323",
            "aadhaar_number": "4561221211212",
            "center_id": "4"
        }
],
    "message": "Patient searched successfully!"
}
```

Model Class

```
public class SearchModel {


public SearchModel(String patient_id, String gen_patient_id, String first_name, String last_name, String p_mobile, String aadhaar_number, String center_id) {
    this.patient_id = patient_id;
    this.gen_patient_id = gen_patient_id;
    this.first_name = first_name;
    this.last_name = last_name;
    this.p_mobile = p_mobile;
    this.aadhaar_number = aadhaar_number;
    this.center_id = center_id;
}

private String patient_id;

public String getPatientId() { return this.patient_id; }

public void setPatientId(String patient_id) { this.patient_id = patient_id; }

private String gen_patient_id;

public String getGenPatientId() { return this.gen_patient_id; }

public void setGenPatientId(String gen_patient_id) { this.gen_patient_id = gen_patient_id; }

private String first_name;

public String getFirstName() { return this.first_name; }

public void setFirstName(String first_name) { this.first_name = first_name; }

private String last_name;

public String getLastName() { return this.last_name; }

public void setLastName(String last_name) { this.last_name = last_name; }

private String p_mobile;

public String getPMobile() { return this.p_mobile; }

public void setPMobile(String p_mobile) { this.p_mobile = p_mobile; }

private String aadhaar_number;

public String getAadhaarNumber() { return this.aadhaar_number; }

public void setAadhaarNumber(String aadhaar_number) { this.aadhaar_number = aadhaar_number; }

private String center_id;

public String getCenterId() { return this.center_id; }

public void setCenterId(String center_id) { this.center_id = center_id; }



@Override
public String toString()
{
    return "ClassPojo [first_name = "+first_name+", aadhaar_number = "+aadhaar_number+", last_name = "+last_name+", patient_id = "+patient_id+", center_id = "+center_id+", p_mobile = "+p_mobile+", gen_patient_id = "+gen_patient_id+"]";
}
```

}

Result Model Class

```
public class Result {


private SearchModel[] result;

public SearchModel[] getResult() {
    return result;
}

public void setResult(SearchModel[] result) {
    this.result = result;
}
```

}

My Recycler Adapter

```
 public class PatientSearchAdapter extends 
RecyclerView.Adapter<PatientSearchAdapter.ViewHolder>  {
private ArrayList<SearchModel> searchList;
private Context context;

public PatientSearchAdapter(ArrayList<SearchModel> searchList){
    this.searchList = searchList;
}

@Override
public PatientSearchAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(final ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.search_list_row_new,parent,false);
    PatientSearchAdapter.ViewHolder viewHolder = new PatientSearchAdapter.ViewHolder(view);
    return viewHolder;
}


@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(PatientSearchAdapter.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {

    holder.p_name_first.setText( (searchList.get(position).getFirstName()).substring(0,1).toUpperCase() + (searchList.get(position).getFirstName()).substring(1));
    holder.p_name_last.setText( (searchList.get(position).getLastName()).substring(0,1).toUpperCase() + (searchList.get(position).getLastName()).substring(1));
    holder.p_mobile.setText(searchList.get(position).getPMobile());
    holder.p_Id.setText(searchList.get(position).getGenPatientId().toUpperCase());


    holder.view_history.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Context context = v.getContext();
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, ViewPatientActivity.class);
            context.startActivity(intent);

        }
    });

    holder.take_test.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Context context = v.getContext();
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, HealthServicesActivity.class);
            context.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

}



@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return searchList.size();
}



public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    TextView p_name_first,p_mobile,p_Id,p_name_last;

    Button take_test;
    TextView view_history;

    public ViewHolder(View v) {
        super(v);


        p_name_first = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.ppatient_name);
        p_name_last = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.ppatient_last_name);
        p_mobile = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.pmobile_number);
        p_Id=(TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.pp_id);
        view_history=(TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.pview_text_1);
        take_test=(Button) v.findViewById(R.id.ptake_test_button);


    }
}
 }
```

My Fragment

```
public class PatientListFragment extends Fragment implements 
View.OnClickListener {

View view;

@BindView(R.id.search_text)
EditText searchText;
@BindView(R.id.item_search_click)
ImageButton saerchButton;



private ProgressBar progressBar;

Api webService = ServiceGenerator.getApi();

SharePreferenceManager<LoginModel> sharePreferenceManager;

private PatientSearchAdapter mSearchAdapter;
@BindView(R.id.recycler_patient_search_list)
RecyclerView recyclerViewOnSearch;
ArrayList<SearchModel> searchList = new ArrayList<SearchModel>();




public PatientListFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor

}



@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    view= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_patient_list, container, false);
    ButterKnife.bind(this,view);




    sharePreferenceManager = new SharePreferenceManager<>(getActivity());

    progressBar =(ProgressBar) view.findViewById(R.id.progress_bar);

   /* progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
    progressDialog.setMessage("Please Wait...");
    progressDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);*/


    EditText searchView = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.search_text);

initialViewsForSearch();



    return view;

}


    private void initialViewsForSearch() {
    recyclerViewOnSearch.setHasFixedSize(true);
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    recyclerViewOnSearch.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);



@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    if (NetworkUtils.isNetworkAvailableToastIfNot(getActivity())) {
        getPayientSearchListOnline(
                sharePreferenceManager.getUserLoginData(LoginModel.class).getResult().getCenterId(),
                sharePreferenceManager.getUserLoginData(LoginModel.class).getResult().getTabID(),
                ComponentUtils.getInputStringFromView(searchText));

    }

}

    saerchButton.setOnClickListener(this);
}

/**
 * Searching For Patient List
 * @param centerId
 * @param tabID
 * @param searchtext
 */
    private void getPayientSearchListOnline(String centerId, String tabID,String searchtext){

    progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    Call<Result> profileModelCall = webService.getPatientSearchList(getMap(centerId,tabID,searchtext));
    profileModelCall.enqueue(new Callback<Result>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<Result> call, Response<Result> response) {
            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                //if (response.body().isStatus()) {
                recyclerView.setVisibility(View.GONE);


                Result jsonResponse = response.body();
                searchList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(jsonResponse.getResult()));
                mSearchAdapter = new PatientSearchAdapter(searchList);
                recyclerViewOnSearch.setAdapter(mSearchAdapter);


            } else {
                APIError apiError = ErrorUtils.parseError(response);

                Toast.makeText(context, ""+ apiError.message(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }


            if (progressBar.isEnabled())
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<Result> call, Throwable t) {

            Toasty.error(getActivity(), "Please Try Again", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT, true).show();
            if (progressBar.isEnabled())
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    });
}


   /* *
   * preparing Map data with param data
   */
private Map<String, RequestBody> getMap(String centerId, String tabId, String searchText) {
    //All the String parameters, you have to put like
    Map<String, RequestBody> map = new HashMap<>();

    if (sharePreferenceManager != null && sharePreferenceManager.isUserLogin())

        map.put("center_id", toRequestBody(centerId));
        map.put("tabID", toRequestBody(tabId));
        map.put("patient_search", toRequestBody(searchText));




    return map;
}

/**
 * This method  converts String to RequestBody
 */
public static RequestBody toRequestBody(String value) {

    return RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), value);


}
```

Api Call Interface

```
@Multipart   
@POST(WebServices.GET_SEARCH_LIST)    
Call<Result> getPatientSearchList(@PartMap Map<String, RequestBody> params);
```

what i am trying to do here is i am taking  1 edit text where i am putting number to enter , sending centerid,and tabID as parameter  and for that i am doing Api Calling using Retrofit. but my problem is that whenever it goes to  public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) {
it comes out from there and goes to failure and i am not getting the result after clicking the button.its showing me nothing .

Comment: Can you log the throwable passed to your onFailure and share it? Maybe there will be some useful information in it.

Comment: After debugging ProfileModel.enqueue(new Callback<Result>() {    it's coming out and its not going to OnFailure Call also.ProfileModel.enqueue(new Callback<Result>(){ Here it's giving ExecutorCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallbackCall@830041023344

Comment: In console its giving me result Keep-Alive
D/OkHttp: Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
D/OkHttp: {"status":true,"result":[{"patient_id":"22","gen_patient_id":"pmhsola00022","first_name":"rty","last_name":"rty","p_mobile":"9988776655","aadhaar_number":"999888777696","center_id":"4"}],"message":"Patient searched successfully!"}
D/OkHttp: <-- END HTTP (2151-byte body)
D/jdwp:     --> RUNNING, SUSPENDED

Comment: i have updated my question with model classes please go through it once @macmist

Comment: try to log the error message in `onFailure` method with `t.getErrorMessage` and post the logs here.
we cant help if we dont know what the error is

Comment: @Sujal Can you post also the code that receives the response, so that we can see what happens.

Comment: can change @FormUrlEncoded
@POST(WebServices.GET_SEARCH_LIST)    
Call<Result> getPatientSearchList(@Field("center_id") String center_id, @Field("tabID") String tabID, @Field("patient_search") String patient_search);

Comment: i have tried this way also still facing the same problem. @Bhuvaneshwaran

Comment: what is failure response code?

Comment: @Sujal can you provide the full stack trace? From the look of your OkHttp log, the http call return correctly, the error might be when converting the result to your model

Comment: so how to solve that should i change my Model class ? @macmist

Comment: That might be a solution but first please share the full stacktrace of your error so we can be sure that this is what is causing the error. From the one line you shared before it was not enough to identify the issue